# App isn't responding. Using ListActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-activity

When I try to launch application it closes before even shows something. I use ListActivity and I was using this site to write the code : [Android ListActivity Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/listactivity/android-listactivity-example/). I think everything is good in code. What can it be then?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

static int kiekis, n = 10000, s = 20000, f = 30000, p1 = 40000, p2 = 50000, pozicija, i = 1;
ArrayList<String> list;
static String vardas;
static String numeris;
static String skype;
static String facebook;
static String papildoma1;
static String papildoma2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences sprefs = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (i = 1; i <= kiekis; i++) {
        vardas = sprefs.getString(String.valueOf(i), "");
        list.add(vardas);
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_view, R.id.vardas, list));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detail.class);

    pozicija = position;

    SharedPreferences sprefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    numeris = sprefs.getString(String.valueOf(n + position), "");
    skype = sprefs.getString(String.valueOf(s + position), "");
    facebook = sprefs.getString(String.valueOf(f + position), "");
    papildoma1 = sprefs.getString(String.valueOf(p1 + position), "");
    papildoma2 = sprefs.getString(String.valueOf(p2 + position), "");

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Show us the logcat for that bad boy

Comment: Well, I can't. That's why I write here

Comment: The logcat should get posted in your IDE, you can copy and paste it here. without that it will be hard for us to tell.

Comment: you havn't assigned value to kiekis and using in a loop

Comment: I saw that after I posted this question. I assigned value to kiekis, but no luck

Comment: @NeimantasJocius what value did you assign? And try removing your declaration of `i` at the top, it can cause scope issues with the `i` in the `for` loop or just rename it (unless the naming was intentional) then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting break point on the First line and run in debug mode. Then you can see where it breaks